# mongodb query for results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

```
[
    {
        "userid": "abcde",
        "dates": {
            "2-01-2015": {
                "9-10": {
                    "ava": "yes",
                    "bookibg_id": "null"
                },
                "10-11": {
                    "ava": "yes",
                    "bookibg_id": "null"
                }
            },
            "3-01-2015": {
                "9-10": {
                    "ava": "no",
                    "bookibg_id": "null"
                },
                "10-11": {
                    "ava": "no",
                    "bookibg_id": "null"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "userid": "abcde",
        "dates": {
            "2-01-2015": {
                "9-10": {
                    "ava": "yes",
                    "bookibg_id": "null"
                },
                "10-11": {
                    "ava": "no",
                    "bookibg_id": "null"
                }
            },
            "3-01-2015": {
                "9-10": {
                    "ava": "no",
                    "bookibg_id": "null"
                },
                "10-11": {
                    "ava": "no",
                    "bookibg_id": "null"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I am relatively new to nosql db and mongodb.Its kind of confusing how to query these.
for the given db how do i write query to generate results:
Query:List userids such that at "2-01-2015",the "ava" is "yes" at "9-10".
Plzz also explain the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can find using

```
db.coll.find({'dates.2-01-2015.9-10.ava': "yes"},{"userid":1,'_id':0})
```

Here as **'dates.2-01-2015.9-10.ava':'yes'** is used to find the value of ava as yes similary accessing a value from JSON objects  and second argument is used to get only userid from query **{"userid":1,'_id':0}**

the output will be

```
{ "userid" : "abcde" }
{ "userid" : "abcde" }
```

if you remove second argument you'll get entire document in your result based on your second argument you can filter the feilds that you want